# vue webpack template missing parser

Tags: webpack, vue.js, prettier

I was just setting up a vue project using the webpack template like stated here: http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/

However after running npm run dev just to test that the template is working, I get this error:

```
Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           21:49:02
 error  in ./src/App.vue

Module build failed: Error: No parser and no file path given, couldn't infer a parser.
    at normalize (path\node_modules\prettier\index.js:7051:13)
    at formatWithCursor (path\node_modules\prettier\index.js:10370:12)
    at path\node_modules\prettier\index.js:31115:15
    at Object.format (path\node_modules\prettier\index.js:31134:12)
    at Object.module.exports (path\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\template-compiler\index.js:80:23)

 @ ./src/App.vue 11:0-354
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Module build failed: Error: No parser and no file path given, couldn't infer a parser.
    at normalize (path\node_modules\prettier\index.js:7051:13)
    at formatWithCursor (path\node_modules\prettier\index.js:10370:12)
    at path\node_modules\prettier\index.js:31115:15
    at Object.format (path\node_modules\prettier\index.js:31134:12)
    at Object.module.exports (path\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\template-compiler\index.js:80:23)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like I beat you to the question by one minute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555943/running-into-couldnt-infer-parser-error-using-vue-cli

Comment: Looks like there's an error in vue-cli, downgrade probably

Comment: I'm getting this issue with vue and webpack; there's no vue-cli in use in my project at all. It isn't even installed.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[Prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier) has caused this regression in their `1.13.0` update which occurred today. Downgrade to the previous version to fix this error:

> npm install --save-dev prettier@1.12.0
>
> npm run dev

That should do the trick.

Comment: Worked great for me using npm. Thanks!

Comment: Now removing node_modules and package-lock.json and `npm install` will fix it.

Comment: This works for me! Wow, one bad update to 1 package and the whole project breaks. That's the current state of the javascript landscape

Answer (score 8):

it is fixed in vue-loader@13.7.2 and vue-loader@14.2.3. So just upgrade.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Yarn add this to your `package.json` to force `@vue/component-compiler-utils` to use the right version:

```json
"resolutions": {
  "@vue/component-compiler-utils/prettier": "1.12.1"
}
```

Then do a fresh install.

[reference](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)

Comment: But change the version of prettier to 1.12.0 works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `laravel-mix` then this fixed it for me:

Remove .\node_modules, remove .\yarn.lock then add following to .\package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "prettier": "1.12.1",
    "vue-loader": "13.7.0"
    ...
},
"resolutions": {
    "laravel-mix/vue-loader": "13.7.0",
    "vue-loader/prettier": "1.12.1"
}
```

run yarn and all should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Since `vue-cli` uses prettier API interface here and hardcoded the options, and prettier dependency was added in project `@vue/component-compiler-utils`.

You could try `npm i prettier@~1.12.0` to force the prettier version here.

BTW someone did a [pull request](https://github.com/vuejs/component-compiler-utils/pull/15) with the fix

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with yarn, but tried `npm i` and `npm run dev` instead and it worked.

`yarn v v1.5.1`
`npm -v 5.6.0`
`node -v v10.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I use Nuxt/Vue on Docker. I got same error with docker build.

It doesn't work after below commands

```
rm -rf node_modules 
npm install --save-dev prettier@1.12.0
npm run dev
```

So I edited Dockerfile like this and it worked.

```
FROM node:8.11

RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install && npm cache verify
RUN npm install --save-dev prettier@1.12.0
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "express"]
```