# Module build failed: Error: No parser and no file path given, couldn't infer a parser in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, prettier

```
    Module build failed: Error: No parser and no file path given, couldn't infer a parser.
    at normalize (/home/nayan/dd_pwa/node_modules/prettier/index.js:7051:13)
    at formatWithCursor (/home/nayan/dd_pwa/node_modules/prettier/index.js:10370:12)
    at /home/nayan/dd_pwa/node_modules/prettier/index.js:31115:15
    at Object.format (/home/nayan/dd_pwa/node_modules/prettier/index.js:31134:12)
    at Object.module.exports (/home/nayan/dd_pwa/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js:80:23)

 @ ./layouts/error.vue 7:0-368
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js
```

I'm having [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555943/running-into-couldnt-infer-parser-error-using-vue-cli/50556466) on Nuxtjs. Anyone facing same issue??? Help?!!
version: 
"nuxt": "^1.0.0",
"prettier": "^1.12.1"

Tried all the option of downgrading and upgrading prettier version.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555953/vue-webpack-template-missing-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555953/vue-webpack-template-missing-parser)

Comment: already tried downgrading and upgrading prettier version. Not worked

Answer (score 27, accepted):

UPDATE:
I mentioned this in the comment below but for some reason people still refer to the same thing.

### Please note that this is a hack... A temporary one at that. But it's meant for people who want to get their work done right now... While waiting for a permanent fix to ship. As you might have guessed... A PR has already been submitted and already been merged. Which means a fix is coming within the next release. In the meantime... This will do. And yes when that release comes in it will override this hack and none of this would seem to have happened. Cheers

Dont even bother to downgrade.
Its a minor issue.
I gave an explanation and [what worked for me here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555943/running-into-couldnt-infer-parser-error-using-vue-cli/50565355#50565355)
In a nutshell:
Go to:
 `node_modules\vue-loader\lib\template-compiler` ...open `index.js` and look for

`// prettify render fn
    if (!isProduction) {
      code = prettier.format(code, { semi: false})
    }`

and change the lines to:

```
// prettify render fn
if (!isProduction) {
  code = prettier.format(code, { semi: false, parser: 'babylon' })
}
```

Thats it!

Comment: but this is a temporary fix, surely downgrading is safer?

Comment: This is just a hack instead of a fix.

Comment: As I already mentioned downgrading and upgrading of prettier version not working in Nuxtjs. So this as a temporary fix working.

Comment: Yes Gerald and Hardik. This is a hack... A temporary one at that. But it's meant for people who want to get their work done right now... While waiting for a permanent fix to ship. As you might have guessed... A PR has already been submitted and already been merged. Which means a fix is coming within the next release. In the meantime... This will do. And yes when that release comes in it will override this hack and none of this would seem to have happened. Cheers.

Comment: This is a hack, and not a long-term viable solution.

Comment: great, very helpfull

Comment: Now use `parser: 'babel'` instead

Answer (score 30):

Downgrade `prettier` package to version 1.12.1 and stick with it:

`npm i prettier@1.12.1 --save-dev --save-exact`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sed one-liner that fixes it for now:

```
sed -i 's/semi: false/semi: false, parser: \"babylon\"/g' node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js
```

And for mac:

```
sed -i '' 's/semi: false/semi: false, parser: \"babylon\"/g' node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js
```

And as an npm script:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "sed -i 's/semi: false/semi: false, parser: \"babylon\"/g' node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js"
}
```